Quarkus ManagedExecutor vs WorkerExecutor vs VirtualThreads for blocking code
I have a quarkus reactive application in which I need to use sqlite. Sqlite does not have a reactive implementation, so I am trying to understand the suggested way to execute non-reactive code, possibly inheriting the transaction, and exposing the result as Uni, to integrate the code wihtin my application.
I saw that ManagedExecutor does provide that out-of-the-box, but I did read that WorkerExecutor are better suited for long running tasks.
Regarding VirtualThreads I did read about the downsides but, quite frankly, I can't really understand how much they apply to my current problem.
Anyone that already faced this problems and can give me a hint?
Marco.

Since you do not provide any code, it is hard to say if any approach potentially causes an issue. Judging by just the fact that you want to include non-reactive code and have transaction propagated, I'd say ManagedExecutor will work (for the transaction propagation). However, there are more ways to mix reactive and imperative, I suggest you take a look at this guide.
Without actual code, the best bet is to just try it out and see if you run into any trouble.

thanks @siliarus I'll try with ManagedExecutor first. I was looking for guidelines instead of starting directly with implementations. I did start reading the documentation, but I personally feel the is not very clear about when to use what.

I don’t see any benefit why you would do this. This is going to run your code in a worker thread (maybe from a different pool than the default one), while it already does when you write blocking code.

Virtual threads might be an excellent choice for executing non-reactive code in reactive application, but you mentioned a necessity of Transaction propagation to a "slow" I/O blocking threads, and that raises a number of questions.
Transaction propagation or, more generally, Context Propagation is addressed by Quarkus documentation. This article discusses two major approaches: with Mutiny and with CompletionStage, which is based on SmallRye implementation of context propagation primitives ThreadContext and ManagedExecutor.
Things with ThreadContext and ManagedExecutor are pretty straightforward as this design directly targets ThreadLocals, set in a thread when Transaction is started, to other threads. It is enough to set up virtual thread-based ManagedExecutor:
SmallRyeManagedExecutor managedExecutor = SmallRyeManagedExecutor.builder()
    .withExecutorService(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor())
    .build();

        

and then use it in a way the snipped in the article suggests:
return threadContext.withContextCapture(...)
    .thenApplyAsync(response -> {
        return ...;
    }, managedExecutor);

Things become a bit more complex with Mutiny. If minimal intervention to VertX thread management is required, then it is possible to reuse EnhancedQueueExecutor, passing to its Builder virtual thread factory:
Executor executor = new EnhancedQueueExecutor.Builder()
    .setThreadFactory( (r) -> Thread.ofVirtual().unstarted(r))
    .setContextHandler(new VertxCoreRecorder().executionContextHandler(true))
    .build();
    

and then again the Mutiny-oriented snipped from the article will look just the same:
 return Multi.createFrom().publisher(...)
     .select().first(...)
     .emitOn(executor)
     .map({
         ....
         return price;
      });
    

except that custom virtual thread executor replaces default one. Notice that this solution also propagates VertX Context, io.vertx.core.Context, to blocking, non-reactive, virtual in our case, thread. This VertX context and its propagation is discussed in Quarkus documentation.
If VertX Context propagation (as well as the service of EnhancedQueueExecutor) isn't necessary, then the snippet may look like this:
 return Multi.createFrom().publisher(...)
     .select().first(...)
     .emitOn(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor())
     .map({
         ....
         return price;
      });
             

There is one caveat in all above solutions: while ThreadLocals that carry Transaction and other things will be correctly propagated to virtual threads by Virtual Thread machinery, the excessive usage of ThreadLocals is not recommended by Loom:

... use of thread-local variables is perfectly reasonable with virtual threads. However, consider using the safer and more efficient scoped values. See Scoped Values for more information.

Indeed, with ScopedValue  the Context Propagation becomes trivial and no complicated machinery is necessary as the propagation is handled by Java itself. ScopedValue, however, cannot be used for Quarkus Transaction propagation as Quarkus hardcodes the usage of ancient Arjuna/Narayana Transaction Management, custom Transaction Manager is not possible with Quarkus, and Arjuna, in turn, hardcodes the usage of ThreadLocal.
